# Without using a calculator can you say, which number is greater, $65^{1662}$ or $33^{1995}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function

Without using a calculator can you say, which number is greater,  $65^{1662}$ or $33^{1995}$?

first i thought we can say which is bigger by differences.
 
Like Here **difference of base : 65–33=32**.
     Here **difference of exponent : 1995–1662=333**.
Difference of exponents are bigger than difference of base. so I think I should consider the biggest number by bigger difference. So i considered $33^{1995}$ as bigger number and I was right. 
**$33^{1995}$ is bigger then $65^{1662}$ .**
But then i took another example **$21^{6}$** and **$81^{4}$**.
Here **difference of base : 81–21=60**.
Here **difference of exponent : 6–4=2**.
Then as before here also i considered bigger number by bigger difference.
So here base has the bigger difference than exponent.
So according to the bigger difference of base i considered bigger number by bigger difference and that was 81^3.
But I was wrong at this point.
**$21^{6}$ is bigger than $81^{3}$**

**Then What is the correct way of finding the bigger number ?**

Comment: In general, in such a situation, one approach is to take the logarithm of each expression. Without a calculator, you may try to find approximation/bound on $\log 65$ and $\log 33$

Comment: Could you give us some context for this question?  Where did you come across this?  Is there a reason that you believe that there is a nice way of finding the bigger number without a calculator?

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: @Pspl I didn't downvote but the argument in the text is really off: "Difference of exponents are bigger than difference of base". Also, why would you want to avoid computing the logarithm?

Answer (score 6):

There are two things to note here:

1. $65$ is just less than $2 \times 33$
2. $\frac{1995}{1662}$ is just greater than $\frac{6}{5}$

This suggests the following approach:

$65^{1662} < 66^{1662} = 2^{1662} \times 33^{1662} = 32^{\frac{1662}{5}} \times 33^{1662}$

I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: Great approach.

Answer (score 2):

If we divide both numbers by $33^{1662}$, we see that it's enough to find the bigger number between
$$
\frac{65^{1662}}{33^{1662}} = \left(\frac{65}{33}\right)^{1662} \quad \text{and} \quad 
\frac{33^{1995}}{33^{1662}} = 33^{333}.
$$
It suffices to note that
$$
\left(\frac{65}{33}\right)^{1662} < 2^{1662} = 32^{1662/5} = 32^{332.4} < 33^{333}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rules of exponentiation. When you have $21^6$ and $81^3$, these can be rewritten as $(21^2)^3$ and $81^3$, so the question becomes: which is bigger out of $21^2$ and $81$? Taking a root of both, and noting $21 > 9$ then yields your answer.

The important thing is to try to get the two numbers on the same exponents, possibly by estimating them from the correct side. As a rule of thumb, you might say that the exponent is almost always the most important element.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the log of both sides

$1662 \log 65 <?> 1995 \log 33$

$\log 65 < \log 66 = \log 33 + \log 2$

$1662 \log 65 < 1662 \log 33 + 1662 \log 2$

We can choose what base to use for our logs, lets choose log base 2

$5 < \log_2 33$

$1995 = 1662 + 333$

$1662 \log_2 33 + 1662 < 1662 \log_2 33 + 1665 < 1995 \log_2 33$